# How to Plug and Play a USB Barcode-Printer in android devices

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, device-firmware, usb-drivers, usb-host-mode, barcode

We are trying to print Barcode using USB Barcode Printer from an android device.

The available printer model is GODEX EZ520, we used printer-share app from Playstore and it detected the printer-device but they do not have supporting drivers for this printer.

Do we need to write separate drivers for printers to print from android or Is there any other ways to connect android device and Barcode Printers via usb.